# UITapGestureRecognizer conflicting with each other

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitapgesturerecognizer

So I have two UITapGestureRecognizer one is for a single tap and the other one is for a double tap. However when I do a double tap, the single tap action gesture recognizer is triggered as well. Is there a way to disable this so that double tap calls the double tap action only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];
```